# Why onDraw() calling constantly?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I've a small application which uses customized LinearLayout, called LinearlayoutOutlined. I want to draw different sized and coloured boxes in it. It has also two text labels indicating time intervals. The layout has to be redraw after some user action. Therefore I do refresh the layout as is

```
slotPanel.setDayBoundariesInMinutes( db, dw );
TimeSlot[] tSlots = nextDaysSlots.getGaps( dayOfWeek );
slotPanel.setItems( tSlots );
slotPanel.invalidate();
```

where *slotpanel* is the *LinearLayoutOutlined* instance.

I detected that the onDraw method is called constantly. It is not stops calling after  particular number of cycles.

Here is the whole LinearLayoutOutlined class:

package com.widgets;

```
public class LinearLayoutOutlined extends LinearLayout {
    private int workingTimeBeginsInMinutes;
    private int workingTimeFinishesInMinutes;
    private TimeSlot[] items;
    private Rect outline;
    private Paint strokePaint = new Paint();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter;
    public LinearLayoutOutlined( Context context ) {
        super( context );
        setWillNotDraw( false );
    }
    public LinearLayoutOutlined( Context context, AttributeSet attrs ) {
        super( context, attrs );
        setWillNotDraw( false );
    }
    public void setWorkingTimeBeginsInMinutes( int m ) {
        this.workingTimeBeginsInMinutes = m;
    }
    public void setWorkingTimeFinishesInMinutes( int m ) {
        this.workingTimeFinishesInMinutes = m;
    }
    public void setDayWidthInMinutes( int dayWidthInMinutes ) {
        this.workingTimeFinishesInMinutes = this.workingTimeBeginsInMinutes +  dayWidthInMinutes;
    }
    public void setDayBoundariesInMinutes( int daybeginInMinutes, int dayWidthInMinutes ) {
        setWorkingTimeBeginsInMinutes( daybeginInMinutes );
        setDayWidthInMinutes( dayWidthInMinutes );
    }
    private int getWorkingTimeBeginsInMinutes() {
        return workingTimeBeginsInMinutes;
    }
    public int getWorkingTimeFinishesInMinutes() {
        return workingTimeFinishesInMinutes;
    }
    public void setItems( TimeSlot[] items ) {
        this.items = items;
    }
    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    @Override
    protected void onDraw( Canvas canvas ) {
        if( items == null ) return;
        // time labels
        TextView tvFrom = ( TextView )findViewById( R.id.lblStartingTime ), tvTo = ( TextView )findViewById( R.id.lblFinishingTime );
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat( "HH:mm", Locale.getDefault() );
        tvFrom.setText( formatter.format( new Date( getWorkingTimeBeginsInMinutes() * 60000L ) ) );
        tvTo.setText( formatter.format( new Date( getWorkingTimeFinishesInMinutes() * 60000L ) ) );
        strokePaint.setStyle( Paint.Style.STROKE );
        strokePaint.setStrokeWidth( 1 );
        strokePaint.setStyle( Style.FILL );
        outline = canvas.getClipBounds();
        Convert.setDayBoundaries( getWorkingTimeBeginsInMinutes(), getWorkingTimeFinishesInMinutes(), outline );
        for( TimeSlot slotItem: items ) {
            RectTouchable rect = Convert.ToRect( slotItem );
            if( slotItem.isFree() )
                strokePaint.setARGB( 255, 0, 255, 0 );
            else
                strokePaint.setARGB( 255, 255, 0, 0 );
            canvas.drawRect( rect.getRect(), strokePaint );
        }
    }
}
```

Please give me some idea, what should I do?
Thanx in advance

---

**I don't understand why I cannot add comment to my own question?!?**

**@Romain Guy:**
Thank you! OK I understand. But I have to setText() together with drawin boxes. The textlabels are overlayed, they are the topmost. What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every time you call `setText()` on a `TextView` the UI toolkit needs to relayout and repaint the UI. Since you are doing this every time `onDraw()` is called you've basically created an infinite drawing loop.

There are other issues in your draw method as well: you should not do a `findViewById()` every time, you should not create a new `SimpleDateFormat` every time, you should not create new `Date` objects every time, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the infinite loop if you call setText in onDraw() only if the text has changed.
Instead of setText use this method:

```
void setTextIfChanged(TextView tv, CharSequence text) {
    if (!text.equals(tv.getText()))
        tv.setText(text);
}
```